# NSPredicate for a NSFetchResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to create an `NSPredicate` for a `NSFetchResultsController` I am using in a `UITableView`.
I have 3 entities, `User` (1 to many) -> `Visit` (1 to many) -> `Treatment`, and want to get all the treatments that a user has.

I have tried using subqueries, `SELF`, `ANY`, and only get as a return the `Visits` and not the `Treatments`.

Could somebody please guide me on how I can access the treatment entities from the user entities?

Thanks in advance for any help!

[Image of the CoreData Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZpSf.png)

**EDIT**

This is the code I am currently using to try and fetch the treatments

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:kTreatmentVisits];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = descriptors;
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY treatmentVisits = %@.visitTreatment", user.userVisit];
```

As a Result I get the visits, not the treatments

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x60b000148a40> (entity: treatmentVisits; predicate: (ANY treatmentVisits == {<Visits: 0x60b0000a0ad0> (entity: VisitsEntity; id: 0xd0000000000c000a <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/VisitsEntity/p3> ; data: {
visitCause = "";
visitEndDate = nil;
visitId = nil;
visitRecommendation = "";
visitStartDate = "2016-08-11 04:43:50 +0000";
visitTreatment = "<relationship fault: 0x60300025e6d0 'visitTreatment'>";
visitType = 0;
visitUser = "0xd000000001940000 <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/UsersEntity/p101>";
}), <Visits: 0x60b0000bec10> (entity: VisitsEntity; id: 0xd00000000008000a <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/VisitsEntity/p2> ; data: {
visitCause = "";
visitEndDate = nil;
visitId = nil;
visitRecommendation = "";
visitStartDate = "2016-08-04 20:26:33 +0000";
visitTreatment = "<relationship fault: 0x60300025e850 'visitTreatment'>";
visitType = 0;
visitUser = "0xd000000001940000 <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/UsersEntity/p101>";
}), <Visits: 0x60b000148570> (entity: VisitsEntity; id: 0xd00000000010000a <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/VisitsEntity/p4> ; data: <fault>), <Visits: 0x60b000148620> (entity: VisitsEntity; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://5CDB188C-2177-415B-9B74-E30B20EA4DAA/VisitsEntity/p1> ; data: <fault>)}.visitTreatment); sortDescriptors: ((
"(treatmentStartTime, descending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 10; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

I would like to be able to access what is inside of **visitTreatment**

I have also tried

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", user.userVisit];
```

with the same result.

Comment: Would be nice if you posted the requests and predicates that you've tried already.

Comment: Hi @FelipeCypriano, I updated the post with the code I used, and the code I am using, with the result it gave me.

Comment: The log you have provided appears to be the output from logging the fetch request, not the results of executing the fetch.  See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to get the treatments, the underlying fetch for your FRC must specify the Treatments entity:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"TreatmentsEntity"];
```

Then limit the results to the treatments for a given `UsersEntity`, say `requiredUser`, by specifying a predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"treatmentVisits.visitUser == %@", requiredUser];
```

You then need to execute the fetch request, either directly:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();    
} else {
    NSLog(@"Results is %@",results);
}
```

or, for a fetched results controller, you initialise the FRC with your fetchRequest and then call performFetch:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![frc performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
} else {
    NSLog(@"Results %@",frc.fetchedObjects);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Tried it, but the response was the user, and not the treatments.

Comment: Curious.  Please can you show the full code for your fetch request, and the code and output where you log the results.  (Your question shows the log of the fetch request, not the results of the fetch request.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @pbasdf, I was using the wrong variable and checking to early. I saw that with your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Treatment` as the entity to be fetched. The reference two levels up to the user should be trivial, because the reverse relationships are to-one.

The correct predicate would thus be something like

```
NSPredicate(format: "visit.user = $@", user)
```

Your logs indicate that you are fetching visits, not treatments.